# Changing size of desktop icons

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface

On a standard computer, I change the size of the desktop icons by pressing Ctrl + rolling the scroll wheel (the same operation for zooming in or out in most applications).

But how can I change the icons' size on a touch device, like a Surface tablet, without a mouse ? I tried the "pinch-to-zoom" gesture, which works for zooming in or out in most apps, but it does nothing on the desktop.

Comment: Can you do the equivalent of right-clicking in a Surface tablet? If so, then you can adjust the icon size settings from the context menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Surface tablet, you can hold your finger on a blank area of the desktop screen for a few seconds, and a menu window pops up. Pick `Personalize` > `Display` and choose the size of all items on the desktop. There's an option to choose "Custom sizing options" and pick a larger size (up to 200% of the default). [This link shows how to do this](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57568836-285/five-usability-tips-for-microsofts-surface-rt/).

Comment: That's a good solution, but this way it doesn't change **only** the size of the icons. If you try Ctrl + scroll wheel, you'll see that the size of others items (like the taskbar, or the font size) remains unchanged.
But anyway, your answer is a good alternative :-)

Answer (score 3):

Its really simple,

press the CTRL key on your keyboard, and roll the mouse scroll up and down to change the icons of desktop screen.

This method works for every page, if you are on desktop, explorer, or webpage.

Answer (score 1):

On my surface pro 3 I can pinch to zoom the desktop icons by using the type cover touchpad.  It leaves the remaining UI elements the default size.

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Touch-Notebook with with kickass 4K resolution on small display. There is also a windows 8.1 running so I think it will work for surface-users.
It was in fact a little tricky to setup all the sizes.
Not ONLY the Icons - but also icon-text, menu, taskbar, dialogs and so an.
First I had to rightclick (desktop) for screen-resolution. Select the "Make text and other items larger or smaller".
On this page there is a slider to choose the favourite "dots per inch" and make EVERYTHING larger or smaller.
Below you find a "change text size only" which allows additional finetuning of several text sizes.
A reboot is required to see all the changes. Some are shown immediately.
At last everything was perfect for me but really the ICONs to large! Thats why I came here through google. The hint above which tells to "right-click->view->iconsize->small/medium/large" did it for me!

Answer (score -2):

On Windows 8.1 ---> Select a blank area on the Desktop:

(1) Right Click mouse
(2) Click on VIEW and expand the window
(3) Select SMALL ICONS and you are done

Comment: How do you right-click without a mouse?